# Trying to browse indexeddb but I can't find the file on mac osX?

Tags: macos, indexeddb

I followed a simple tutorial creating a to-do app. After following the tutorial and adding a bunch of todo's I like to browse the indexeddb with the sqlite manager add-on.
But when I go to
file:///users/{user}/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/5kaqoz4x.default/
I don't see indexeddb

[image]

order by time

[image]

Where should I look for indexedb?